# Assembly Modify file content

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

After I read a byte from a file in assembly, the current file position is updated. How can I want to modify that byte and than write it in the file on the same position I read it from? I am working in tasm on x8086

```
READ_LOOP:
    MOV AH,3FH
    MOV BX, HANDLE
    MOV CX, 1
    LEA DX, BUFFER
    INT 21H
    INC SI
    ;if no byte was read we reached the end of file or an error occured
    CMP AL, 1
    JB EOF_END_ERR

    ;write the read content to output
    ;MOV AH, 02H
    ;MOV DL, BUFFER
    ;INT 21H

    JMP ENCRYPTING
    JMP FINAL

ENCRYPTING:
    XOR AX,AX
    MOV DL, BUFFER[0]
    ADD DL, NUMBER[0]
    MOV TEMP, DL

    MOV AH, 42H
    MOV BX, HANDLE
    MOV CX,0FFFFH
    MOV DX, 0FFFFH
    MOV AL,1
    INT 21H

    XOR DX,DX
    MOV DL, 65
    MOV BX, HANDLE
    MOV CX,1
    MOV AH, 40H
    INT 21H

    JMP READ_LOOP
```

I tried with the code above, to simply add NUMBER[0] to the ASCII code of the read byte and than write it back in the file. But it doesn't write what it should in the file

Comment: Use function 42h to move the file pointer back.

Comment: @Jester and how can I use it to go back with 1 byte? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Look up the documentation for it in Ralf Brown's interrupt list: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2799.htm

Comment: Are you working in Windows? Which version? System calls are different for different operating systems, and you need a system call to access files. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @DanielH I am working on Windows 10 and I am using dosbox

Comment: So you're using DOS system calls.  (DOSBOX on Win10 is the same as DOSBOX on Linux; all that matters is the legacy DOS environment it emulates.)  If you were writing a program that wasn't already obsolete, it could run natively on modern mainstream OSes using OS-specific system calls.  (With a different set of system calls than DOS provides, as well as different ways of invoking them.)

Comment: @DanielH: Using `int 21h` means this is a 16-bit DOS program, so only DOS and BIOS service functions are available.

Comment: My code works perfectly fine i just checked it. :)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's why I asked it to be tagged. I knew I couldn't answer the question because I hadn't used that environment, but I thought Windows still used `int 21h`. Tagging it dos helps others find it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I knew it probably wasn't the best way even in Windows, but I thought it was still supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use service [AH=42h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah42) for the same. After you have read a byte from the file the file pointer will be updated. Now to replace the previous read byte in the file to something else you need to first move the file pointer one byte backwards (so that it points to the byte that you want to replace) and this can be done with the following code :

**Code to move the file pointer one byte backwards from its current position:**

```
    mov al, 1        ; relative to current file position
    mov ah, 42h      ; service for seeking file pointer
    mov bx, handle
    mov cx, -1       ; upper half of lseek 32-bit offset (cx:dx)
    mov dx, -1       ; moves file pointer one byte backwards (This is important)
    int 21h
```

After the execution of above code you can now overwrite the byte with the new byte and this can be done with the following code:

**Code to write from the current position of file pointer:**

```
    mov ah, 40h          ; service for writing to a file
    mov bx, handle    
    mov cx, 1            ; number of bytes to write
    mov dx, offset char  ; buffer that holds the new character to be written
    int 21h
```

For more about file operation goto [here](http://fleder44.net/312/notes/16Files/Index.html).

Comment: It doesn't work for me only if I put in cx, 0ffffh and in dx 0ffffh as well because that is -1 in C2, I think my problem was that I was not putting the offset in dx

Comment: It's `handle` (as in file handle), not `handler`.  In English, a "handle" is something you can open a door with, for example.  A "handler" is a person who handles bags at the airport, or a function that handles interrupts, or something like that.  (BTW, nice answer, this is nice and clear with good comments, and not a bunch of unnecessary code to make this part of a whole program.)

Comment: @dbogdan Why did you edited your question to ask a different one ? this is not right you have to post a separate question for this. Revert back to previous question and post your new question separately.

Comment: @dbogdan: good catch, fixed this answer to pass a signed offset in CX:DX.  Re: your edit to the question: your code doesn't work because you're using `ah=40h/ int 21h` wrong.  `dx` has to point to bytes in memory.  You're calling it with `DX=65` (and byte ptr `[ds:65]` probably holds garbage or zero).  Read this answer again, it's still the right answer.

Comment: @Ahtisham sorry for editing the question, I am new to stackoverflow and didn't exactly know what should I do and thanks for the answer.